# How many different passwords of length 6 can be formed...

Tags: combinatorics

Each user on a computer system has a password, which is six characters long, where each character is an uppercase letter or digit.  Each password must contain at least one digit.  How many possible passwords are there?

Why am I incorrect in reasoning that the answer is $10*36^5$?  If every password must contain a digit, then there are only $10$ ways to choose one character in the password and $36^5$ ways to choose the other 5 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not taking into account that the digit can occur in any of the six positions. There are $10\cdot36^5$ passwords that begin with a digit. There are also $10\cdot36^5$ passwords that end with a digit; some of these also begin with a digit and have already been counted, but some do not, so your figure of $10\cdot36^5$ is necessarily too small.

The easiest way to count the acceptable passwords is to note that there are $36^6$ six-character strings made up of upper-case letters and digits, and $26^6$ of them are made up entirely of letters, so there are $36^6-26^6$ that include at least one digit.

It is possible to count them directly, but the counting is more complicated. For each of the $6$ positions in the password there are $10\cdot36^5$ passwords having a digit in that position, so to a first approximation there are $6\cdot10\cdot36^5$ acceptable passwords. However, as noted in the first paragraph, this counts some passwords more than once. For each pair of positions in the password there are $10^2\cdot36^4$ passwords having digits in both of those positions, and all of these passwords have been counted twice. Since there are $\binom62$ pairs of positions, we must subtract $\binom62\cdot10^2\cdot36^4$ to get rid of the double-counting. Unfortunately, this overcompensates, and there are further corrections to be made. The net result, given by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), is

$$\sum_{k=1}^6(-1)^{k+1}\binom6k10^k36^{6-k}\;.$$

Either way, the result is $1,867,866,560$.

Comment: Why does $36^6-26^6$ represent ones that include at least one digit? I'm sorry, it is just confusing to me.

Comment: @user1038665: There are $36^6$ altogether. There are $26^6$ that have no digit. $36^6-26^6$ is what’s left after you throw away the ones that have no digit, and those are precisely the ones that have at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

How many passwords are there, ignoring the "at least one digit" requirement? How many passwords are there with no digits all? Now subtract.

---

Your answer is incorrect because not only are there 10 ways to choose the digit, but there are 6 places where this digit can go. If you multiplied your answer by 6, it would now be double counting. Example:

1. Choose the digit 9 to go into position 1, and choose 11119 for the rest of the string.
2. Choose the digit 9 to go into position 6, and choose 91111 for the first 5 characters.

---

Answers: $36^6$, $26^6$, $36^6-26^6$.

Answer (score 0):

I get  0.1867866560000000000E+10 = 1,867,866,560 in agreement with user, Brian M. Scott.  I used the algorithm posted at [Derive an algorithm for computing the number of restricted passwords for the general case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103361/derive-an-algorithm-for-computing-the-number-of-restricted-passwords-for-the-gen#2103361) .  This algorithm provides a general method for solving problems of this type.